# google map doesn't appear if browser zoom 110%

Tags: css, wordpress, google-maps

http://www.desertrat-aev.com/?page_id=241
this link has a map, if I open this link and zoom the browser to 100% even to 110%, it works perfectly fine. 
BUT, if I zoom the browser to 110% and then open this link, google maps doesn't seem to appear, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue..

Comment: HI ,  Stormswept .
just zoom your browser 110% and reopen this link.

Comment: @JRLambert  please provide me  solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay Try this when form page is loaded i think you are using wordpress. so first your page will load then initialize google map.

```
setTimeout(function() { addLoadEvent(loadMap); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { addLoadEvent(addPoints); }, 1000);
```

Comment: although my problem was solved by adding this . but you answer is perfect

Answer (score 2):

You're using setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() { addLoadEvent(loadMap); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { addLoadEvent(addPoints); }, 1000);
```

Values in addPoints methods may have changed when map has loaded.

You might want to use [marker-animations-iteration](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration) instead.